# Does Sivir's ricochet trigger her passive?

Tags: league-of-legends

[Sivir](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Sivir_the_Battle_Mistress)'s passive, Fleet of Foot, gives her a bonus 50 movement speed if she auto-attacks a champion.  If she uses Ricochet to hit a champion, will it trigger her passive?  Or does nothing happen, since Ricochet doesn't trigger on-hit effects.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ricochet buffs your next auto-attack, so it will trigger her passive **but only on the first hit**. Subsequent bounces will not continue to trigger the passive. If I'm not mistaken, her first hit will proc item effects and otherwise act as a normal auto-attack.

Comment: Correct. Sivir's Riccochet procs on-hit effects on the first target only. Her passive is an on-hit effect, and must obey this limitation also.